# Simple Tutorial for web app in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, web-applications

Hello 
I google d a lot but i could not find a tutorial for web app if some one can provide me the with tutorial it would be a great help.
During my search i found this  site http://www.iwebkit.net but could not get the idea i want is basic idea for web app with tutorial .
The website provides info about some iwebkit framework .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try [apple developer site](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/safari/)? Here's the webapp tut: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MakingaWebApp/MakingaWebApp.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004692-CH18

Comment: ya  i looked at it but could not get the tutorial or sample code if u can provide link ,it would be really helpful for me  .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good site with many different tutorial mobile apps and web apps...
 - http://code.tutsplus.com/